# objective c action for button in custom collection view cell

Tags: objective-c

I've made custom collection view cell with image and button. How to create a method for this button by clicking on it I need to know what exactly cell was clicked.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[self.myCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"myGirlCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL1"];
myGirlCollectionViewCell *cellGirl = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cellGirl.girlImg.image = [[_mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"img"];
NSString *name = [[_mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];//the name I want to see in the method!
[cellGirl.btnName addTarget:self action:@selector(clickMe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cellGirl;
}

-(void)clickMe:(UIButton *)button{
//here *name
}
```

How should I give this parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set tag for the button.

```
cellGirl.btnName.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Then inside this method.

```
-(void)clickMe:(UIButton *)button{
//here *name
//check for tag value like this
if (button.tag == 0) 
     {
         // Your code here
     }
}
```